# cron job to back up single database using cpanel

Tags: mysql, cron, cpanel

I am trying to set up a cron job in cpanel to back up a single database.  Currently have one working that backs up ALL of my databases which looks like this:

```
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD --all-databases > /home/full_backup_`date -I`.sql
```

How do i adjust this to back up a single database, say with the name 'database_1'?

As a follow up how do i adjust this if i want to back up two databases, say with the names 'database_1' and 'database_1'

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's all at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Instead of the --all-databases flag, just supply the dbname. Also recommend using the --opt flag.

Comment: ok i think i got it working now--thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1):

Ahoy,

You can backup a single database with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u USER -p PASS database_1  > /path/to/mysqldump.sql
```

or if you would like compressed backups:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u USER -p PASS database_1 | gzip > /path/to/mysqldump.sql.gz
```